# Step up voltage converter / transformer sizing for electric oven

Tags: transformer, converter

I am considering using a step-up voltage converter/transformer to increase the voltage of an outlet (in Los Angeles) from 110 VAC to 220 VAC for use with a 220 VAC electric oven/range (Samsung Model#NE59J3420SS). I'm trying to size/choose the appropriate converter but I'm a little confused on what size I should choose after looking through the oven's [specifications](http://www.samsung.com/us/system/consumer/product/ne/59/j3/ne59j3420ssaa/NE59J3420_021315.pdf) and doing some calculations.

The specs say the two front ranges are 3 kW each, the two rear ranges are 1.2 kW each, and the oven heating element is 800 W. I am thinking that to size the converter, I would need to add these wattages up, giving a total of 2*3+2*1.2+0.8=9.2 kW. But if I calculate the amperage of 9.2 kW with 220 VAC, then I get a current of 9200/220=42 Amps.

Considering that these things would usually be used in a house with a 15-20 Amp circuit breaker, I am left wondering if I'm sizing this incorrectly. It seems to me that no one would be able to operate this thing in a house if they operate at such high amperage, so am I not supposed to add all of the power ratings or am I doing this right but people would just need to have a dedicated high-amperage circuit to operate this in their house?

Lastly, I have read that these converters should be sized two to three times the wattage of the equipment that will be used on the converter. So if I calculate 9.2 kW, then should the converter really be sized for 27.6 kW (if I can even find one that big)? Is the large safety factor of 3 here really necessary, or is it more for applications involving compressors or motors? Are there any special considerations that should be taken into account with these types of converters when sizing them for an application?

Comment: "an outlet" ... they are max 16A, right? (I'm in the UK so not certain) Giving about half the power needed by one front range... Have an electrician put in a proper 220V circuit.

Comment: Fundamentally, no 120V, 15 or even 20A outlet can supply this amount of power. A proper 220V outlet for a stove, installed by an electrician is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In North America, an electric stove will normally have a dedicated 120/240 volt circuit with a 50 Amp two-pole circuit breaker.  Electric stoves are not intended to be operated from a single 120 volt circuit.

A stove (range) outlet looks like:
[image]